# could not retrieve sbt 0.11.3 play2.0

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am using play 2.0 I pulled a project from a repository and tried to run it but I get the following error. I am new to play can anyone guide me what is going wrong here and how can i fix it. Thanks

```
webapp $ play
 Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.11.3 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3

==== local: tried

  /usr/local/bin/../Cellar/play/2.0.1/bin/../libexec/framework/../repository/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/ivys/ivy.xml

==== Maven2 Local: tried

  file:///Users/Eric/.m2/repository/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/sbt_2.9.1-0.11.3.pom

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

  http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/ivys/ivy.xml

==== Maven Central: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/sbt_2.9.1-0.11.3.pom

==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried

  http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/sbt_2.9.1-0.11.3.pom

==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository: tried

  http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/sbt_2.9.1-0.11.3.pom

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
 unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3: not found
 Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
 (see /usr/local/bin/../Cellar/play/2.0.1/bin/../libexec/framework/sbt/boot/update.log    for complete log)
 Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.11.3
```

Comment: Update your local play sources to newest stable version (or to version used by module) - currently it's `2.0.4`

Comment: Thanks for the reply yes i did it and it worked :)